# Combinatorics: number of possible plates with exactly two T's

Tags: combinatorics

The question in my Textbook goes like this: Suppose that in a certain Jurisdiction, license plates have 4 (uppercase) letters followed by 3 (0-9) digits: whats the number of plates that have exactly two T's and end with 5?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many ways are there to select the position of the T's? How many choices do you have for the other letters? How many choices do you have for the first and second digits?

Comment: I tried to answer the first question before but without success. For the second there are 25 letters left and 9 digits for the third question.

Comment: Why is it not 10 digits? & Do you know what $4 \choose 2$ means?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I was thinking about some other question where the number of digits where 9 and not 10, and so i got affected. And yes, I know what  $4 \choose 2$ means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ${4\choose2}=\frac{4*3}{2!}=6$ unique "pairs" of letters that you could have as your T's. (You can think of this as multiplying the number of "choices" for the position of T number one, 4, by the number of "choices" for the position of T number two, 3, and then dividing by $2!$ to account for the number of ways that you can rearrange your T's (since the two T's are actually indistinguishable))

Now, since you have exactly 2 T's, your remaining letters can be any letter but T. That is, you have 25 choices for each.

Last, since the final digit is predetermined, you only have "choices" for what the first 2 digits are. They can be any of the 10 digits 0-9, so you have 10 choices for each.

Putting this all together, you have
$${4 \choose 2}*25*25*10*10=6*25^2*10^2=375000$$

total possibilities.

Comment: Okay. After reading through your answer I got another (probably) easier way to think about the ways of choosing the positions for the T's: lets take the set {1,2,3,4} where each element represents the position for one T. Then we want the number of all 2-subsets of the form {x, y} where this subset represents the positions for the T's and as they are indistinguishable we took subsets and not sequences. The number of all the 2-subsets will be $4 \choose 2$ (and that's your answer too). everything else is just mainstream. Thanks for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

${4\choose2}$ ways to place the non-T letters

Thus, 6 ways to select two position where T does not occur.

25 choices for both the places

$\implies 25\cdot25\cdot6$ ways for just the letters

first two digits can be anything $\implies$ a total of $10\cdot10$ choices

In total, $25^2\cdot10^2\cdot6$ plates or $375,000$ plates

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I got the answer already.